# Missing axes in figure with multiple subplots

Tags: matlab

I am drawing a figure with multiple subplots with the following code

```
w = 7;
h = 5;

figure;
m = 0.005;
for n = 1:w*h
  [I, J] = ind2sub([w, h], n);
  pos = [(I-1)/w+m, (J-1)/h+m, 1/w-2*m, 1/h-2*m];
  h_axes = subplot(h, w, n, 'position', pos);
  imagesc(rand(10), 'Parent', h_axes);
  axis(h_axes, 'image')
  axis(h_axes, 'off')
end
```

However, only the top two rows are plotted, whereas 5 rows are expected. Going through this code step by step, it seems that lower rows are initially drawn but later upper rows erase them. The axes handles are invalidated, so the axes are not simply hidden but really deleted. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the way you use `subplot`. You can use either syntax:

```
subplot(m,n,p)
```

or

```
subplot('Position',positionVector)
```

... but not both in the same call.